Problem solving while Buffon's needle problem
I'm a student studying probability as a major and got a question while solving Buffon's needle problem.
Buffon needle problem , scenario $\ell>d$
I understood the formula process. However, I'm unsure why I should add $\sin(\theta)$ when solving the following integration.
$$
\frac{4}{tπ}\int^{\pi/2}_0\int^{m(\theta)}_0dxd\theta
$$
where $m(\theta) = \min(\frac{l}{2}\sin\theta, \frac{t}{2})$.

It seems there are flaws in that derivation. The expression for the probability can be derived by carefully integrating the joint probability density function as follows:
The joint probability density function of $x$ and $\theta$:
$f_{X,\Theta}(x,\theta)=
\begin{cases}
\dfrac{4}{t\pi} &:\ 0 \le x \le \dfrac{t}{2}, \ 0 \le \theta \le \dfrac{\pi}{2}\\[4px]
0 &: \text{ elsewhere.}
\end{cases}$
Probability: $P=\displaystyle\int_{\theta=0}^\frac{\pi}{2} \int_{x=0}^{m(\theta)}  \dfrac{4}{t\pi}\,dx\,d\theta$, where $m(\theta)$ is the minimum between $\frac{l}{2}\sin\theta$ and $\frac{t}{2}$.
Since the upper bound of $x$, i.e., $m(\theta)$, can have two values depending on the ranges, we have to split the integral into two integrals.

If $l\sin\theta\leq t$, i.e., $0\leq\theta\leq\arcsin\frac{t}{l}$, then $m(\theta)=\frac{l}{2}\sin\theta$.
If $l\sin\theta>t$, i.e., $\arcsin\frac{t}{l}<\theta\leq\frac{\pi}{2}$, then $m(\theta)=\frac{t}{2}$.

So, the required probability is given by:
$\begin{align*}P=\displaystyle\int_{\theta=0}^\frac{\pi}{2} \int_{x=0}^{m(\theta)}  \dfrac{4}{t\pi}\,dx\,d\theta&=\displaystyle\int_{0}^{\arcsin\frac{t}{l}} \int_{0}^{\frac{l}{2}\sin\theta}  \dfrac{4}{t\pi}\,dx\,d\theta+\displaystyle\int_{\arcsin\frac{t}{l}}^\frac{\pi}{2} \int_{0}^{\frac{t}{2}}  \dfrac{4}{t\pi}\,dx\,d\theta\\&=\dfrac{4}{t\pi}\cdot\dfrac{l}{2}\bigg|-\cos\theta\bigg|_0^{\arcsin\frac{t}{l}}+\dfrac{4}{t\pi}\cdot\dfrac{t}{2}\left(\dfrac{\pi}{2}-\arcsin\dfrac{t}{l}\right)\\&=\frac{2l}{t\pi}\left(1 - \sqrt{1 - \left( \frac t l \right)^2  } \right)+\frac{2}{\pi} \arccos \frac{t}{l}\\&=\dfrac{2l}{t\pi}\left(1-\sqrt{1-\left(\dfrac{t}{l}\right)^2}\right)-\dfrac{2}{\pi}\arcsin\dfrac{t}{l}+1\\&=\frac{2l}{t\pi} - \dfrac{2}{t\pi}\left(\sqrt{l^2 - t^2} + t\arcsin \dfrac{t}{l} \right)+1\end{align*}\tag*{}$
Alternatively, one can use elementary calculus to compute the probability as follows:
$\begin{align*}P&=\displaystyle\dfrac{2}{\pi}\left(\int_0^{\arcsin\frac{t}{l}}\dfrac{l\sin\theta}{t}\ d\theta+\int_{\arcsin\frac{t}{l}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}1\ d\theta\right)\\&=\dfrac{2}{\pi}\left(\dfrac{l}{t}\bigg|-\cos\theta\bigg|_0^{\arcsin\frac{t}{l}}+\dfrac{\pi}{2}-\arcsin\dfrac{t}{l}\right)\\&=\dfrac{2}{\pi}\left(\dfrac{l}{t}\left(1-\sqrt{1-\dfrac{t^2}{l^2}}\right)-\arcsin\dfrac{t}{l}\right)+1\end{align*}\tag*{}$
Hope it helps!

Sorry, but can you explain me how you derive $\frac{2l}{tπ}(1-\sqrt{1-\frac{t}{l}^2})+\frac{2}{π}arccos\frac{t}{l}$ from the former one?

Actually I got $\frac{2l}{πt}(-cos(sin^{-1}(t/l)) + 1) + \frac{2}{π}(\frac{π}{2} - sin^{-1}(t/l))$

Use the identities: $\arcsin x+\arccos x=\frac{\pi}{2}$ and $\cos\theta=\sqrt{1-\sin^2\theta}$.

Oh god. thank you so much!
